# Django Templates: Provide search parameters to {% url %} tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Good evening,

I'd like to have a link that when clicked relocates the page to the faceted search page with a specific facet enacted. For instance, say I have a button that displays a specific author. When a user clicks this button, they are relocated to the search page with all results, filtered by that author.

My search index:

```
class AuthorIndex(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text  = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True, template_name=author_temp_path)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city', null=True, faceted=True)
```

and view:

```
author_sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('city')

author_search_view = AuthorSearchView(
                    searchqueryset=author_sqs,
                    form_class=Author_Search_Form,
                    results_per_page=5,
                    template="search_author.html",)
```

the url is named:

```
url(r'^author/$', 'author_search_view', name='search_author')
```

In my template,

```
<a href='{% url "search_author" with author.city %}'>{{author.city}}</a>
```

Obviously this current link will not work as desired. How can I edit the url tag (and/or the view) so that when the link is clicked, my search_author page comes up with the specific city facet already selected?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'd have to do that with javascript. In your link to the faceted page, set a query parameter, like `&city_facet=new+york`. On the page in javascript, grab your url query parameters, and parse `city_facet`, and make your facets enabled/disabled accordingly

Comment: That's not a simple, elegant solution! You'll get an upvote if this takes me less than 10 minutes and fewer than 8 errors ;)

Comment: Haha sadly it isn't... You can also use the "Network" tab on the chrome web inspector to get clues for how a site like LinkedIn might handle this.